# How do I find the max element in a vector (C++)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, iterator, max

Here's my code. I omitted the code for the vector because it wasn't important.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    vector<int> scores;

    // code to make vector

    cout << "High score: " << scores[std::max(scores.begin(), scores.end())] << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

It is my understanding that std::max returns a iterator, but I don't really know what to do with the iterator. I've seen the example

```
*max(scores.begin(), scores.end())
```

to get it to return an index instead of a iterator, but it get the error

```
Expression: vector iterator not dereferencable
```

I tried using the iterator and then using std::distance

```
vector<int>::iterator high = std::max(scores.begin(), scores.end());
cout << "High score: " << scores[std::distance(scores.begin(), high)] << endl;
```

but I get the error

```
Expression: vector subscript is out of range.
```

What would be the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: You use a function deviously named [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element). `std::max` doesn't do what you seem to think it does, as you could have easily discovered by reading the fine manual.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is standard algorithm named `std::max_element` declared in header `<algorithm>` that does what you need.

For example

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

cout << "High score: " << *std::max_element( scores.begin(), scores.end() ) << endl;
```

It is assumed that the vector is not empty.

As for this call

```
std::max(scores.begin(), scores.end())
```

then it returns maximum iterator among these two iterators. And the iterator that corresponds to `end()` is always greater than or equal to (if the vector is empty) the iterator that corresponds to `begin()`.

Comment: I tried that but my compiler says "std has no member 'max_element'"

Comment: @potapeno You have to include header <algorithm> as it is already written in my post.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't include algorithm... that makes a lot more sense

Comment: @potapeno  Now you know one more standard algorithm in C++.:)

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use max_element:

```
vector<int> scores;
//input
vector<int>::iterator it;
it=max_element(scores.begin(),scores.end());
cout<<*it;
```

If you want the max without any concern of time complexity
you can also use this (not advisable though):

```
sort(scores.begin(),scores.end());
cout<<scores[scores.size()-1];
```

You must use the first way only!